# oracle forms PL/SQL loop with pause

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper, oracleforms

i need your help in creating loop that will go trough the rows and create txt file parameters from each row.
With my current code i can't move further then first record because it is too quick(at least i think this is the reason). I want to add two second pause between each row, but i'm not quote sure how to do it. 
Thanks for your help!

```
PROCEDURE CREATE_TXT_FILE IS
out_file TEXT_IO.FILE_TYPE;
  tmp_file varchar2(100);
  out_str varchar2(100);    
  tmp_str  varchar2(100);
  data_str   varchar2(100); 

BEGIN
      go_block('Block1');
  FIRST_RECORD;
  LOOP


 TMP_FILE := 'C:\txt_files;'      ------directory
  TMP_FILE := TMP_FILE || 'test';                 ------document name



  begin
    out_file := TEXT_IO.FOPEN(tmp_file, 'W');
  exception
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
         bell;
         message('Can''t open file to write.' || tmp_file,acknowledge);
         raise form_trigger_failure;

  END;

 --parameters for text file



  data_str := :block1.column1 ||:block1.column2||:block1.column3||:block1.column4||;
  out_str := out_str || data_str;


  begin
    TEXT_IO.PUT_LINE(out_file, out_str);
  exception when others then
    message('Error to write string to output file. Export is aborted',acknowledge);
    raise form_trigger_failure;
  end;



  TEXT_IO.fclose(out_file);


  message('Done', no_acknowledge);
  synchronize;



        EXIT WHEN :SYSTEM.LAST_RECORD = 'TRUE';
            NEXT_RECORD;
            END LOOP;   
END;
```

Comment: What makes you think it is to quick? I have never seen that be an issue before when writing to files.  It would be more useful to give the error you are getting, and details like whether the file for the first record actually gets created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't open/close the file within the loop. In other words:

- open file
- loop

  - write into file
- end loop
- close file

Pause won't help, it'll just make the whole code way slower. If you want to know what's going on, either

- run the form in debug mode (if your Forms version allows it; 9i onward) or
- put `message` calls into it

so that you could follow the execution.